# How to create a conditional to detect a directory name and its URLs with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a conditional () to trigger the `document.getElementById("testchange")` script. I need it to trigger only from the /eng/ folder onward not just the example.com/eng/ URL which is how its configurred now with the `window.location.pathname == '/eng/'`

```
if(localStorage.getItem('textSet2') && (window.location.pathname == '/eng/')) {
            document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Empieza Ya!";             
}
```

So what is the substitute for `window.location.pathname ==` to trigger the script only for a specific folder name onward, or trigger the script for the `example.com/eng/ folder` and its URLs inside of the folder like `example.com/eng/house.php and example.com/eng/cat.php` and so on?

The  `window.location.pathname  == '/eng/'  only` works for the `example.com/eng/ URL` not the URLs inside of it like `example.com/eng/house.php`, etc. So any ideas of a command to detect folder names and the URLs inside as well. If so how would it look like inside the script i have. Thanx a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var path = window.location.href;

if(path.indexOf('/eng/')>-1){
var myPath = path.substr(path.indexOf('/eng/'));
}

if(localStorage.getItem('textSet2') && (myPath == '/eng/')) {
        document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Empieza Ya!";             
}
```

> `window.location.href` is used to get the full URL of a webpage.

Comment: Hi this script does not seem to work for the intended purposes anyone see why? It looks pretty clear that it should, understand a bit the sintax.  Of course i fixed the bug here, var myPath = path.substr(path.indexOf('/eng/'); there is a missing ) at the end other than that loox fine. Any ideas why?